# How to pull data from table in android app with sqlite3?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Here's my dilemma, I have copy the database on my rooted phone from an app I use called Glide which does video messaging, onto my computer. I cannot figure out how to use sqlite3 to display any information; I have no knowledge with accessing information from a database, but after doing a lot of reading I was able to run this command:

```
SELECT * FROM glideapp-db WHERE Name = GLIDE_MESSAGE;
```

But it always return an error: "Error: near "-": syntax error" What am I doing wrong here?
Also, here are a list of the tables in the database:

```
ALTERNATE_ID
CACHED_VIDEO_MESSAGES_FILES
GLIDE_MESSAGES
GLIDE_THREAD
GLIDE_USER
UI_UPDATE
USERS_THREAD
USER_ACTION
android_metadata
sqlite_squence
```

Comment: Also, how would I pipe the results to a csv or text file?

Comment: you have to surround the `glideapp-deb` with `'` so that it knows that whole thing is a name

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the SQLite Database Browser.

Answer (score 0):

here is a piece of the data that i was looking for:

54.224.0.169;8080;251792257_glide.flixwagon.com_fvm01.glidetalk.com_94243507_v1;90;44100;1;ae19541bafcc5d3c25b11acc9c69d705;glidetalk.flixwagon.com

Is there a way to look at my video message via an internet browser? I noticed that it has domain info in this line.

here's the complete line of data that was extracted with the previous bit of data.

```
_id > 2
MESSAGE_ID > 52cf57ba9c09d5ce59006740
TYPE > video
Content > 'this was blank'
THUMB_URL > http://img.glidetalk.flixwagon.com/ae19541bafcc5d3c25b11acc9c69d705_2.jpg
VIDEO_URL >       54.224.0.169;8080;251792257_glide.flixwagon.com_fvm01.glidetalk.com_94243507_v1;90;44100;1;ae19541bafcc5d3c25b11acc9c69d705;glidetalk.flixwagon.com
DATE_CREATED > 1.38932E+12
```